# Checkbox unchecks automatically

Tags: android, checkbox, material-design

I am using the checkbox of the [Material Design library](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) by navasmdc.

When the fragment with the checkbox is loaded the checkbox gets checked (thats correct) but then it immediately gets unchecked (that's not what I want to)

I have put it into a recycler view item. 
So I set the checkbox inside the onBindViewHolder like that:

```
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ReviewItem current = data.get(position);

        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {

            case TYPE_SIMPLE:
                ViewHolderSimple simpleViewHolder = (ViewHolderSimple) holder;

                simpleViewHolder.title.setText(current.getTitle());
                simpleViewHolder.subtitle.setText("Wert: " + valuesOfMaschine.get(position));

                simpleViewHolder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_starticon);

                if(Integer.parseInt(valuesOfMaschine.get(position)) == 0)
                {
                    //simpleViewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
                } else if(Integer.parseInt(valuesOfMaschine.get(position)) == 1){
                    simpleViewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
                }

                break;

            case TYPE_DETAILED:
                ViewHolderDetailed detailedViewHolder = (ViewHolderDetailed) holder;

                detailedViewHolder.title.setText(current.getTitle());
                detailedViewHolder.subtitle.setText("Wert: " + valuesOfMaschine.get(position));

                detailedViewHolder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_starticon);

                detailedViewHolder.slider.setValue(Integer.parseInt(valuesOfMaschine.get(position)));

                break;
        }
    }
```

I see no part in my code that should be able to uncheck the checkbox again...

the xml of my checkbox:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    >
                    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/review_item_checkbox_simple"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#1E88E5"
                        />

                </RelativeLayout>
```

Do I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

inside onBindViewHolder

```
 simpleViewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position);
 simpleViewHolder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new CheckBoxListener(position));
 simpleViewHolder.checkbox.setClickable(true);
```

create a class for clicklistener

```
class CheckBoxListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        int position;

        CheckBoxListener(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

        public void onClick(View v) {


            boolean isChecked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
            ((CheckBox) v).setChecked(!isChecked);


            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
              // update checked value in the list
            } else {
              // update unchecked value in the list
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


    }
```

Comment: I have copied your code into mine and I do not get any callback. Do I still miss something?

Comment: Okay, I got it working. It was my mistake. I need to update inside of a database when I receive an onclick inside of the fragment that holds the recyclerview. How is it possible to use the updatet data in the viewholder inside the fragment to do a database update ?

Comment: You can directly call the db method inside onclickevent